# Close application when mouse leaves form

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseleave

I try to use mouse leave event handler but i can not work it.

```
private void Form1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();            
}
```

I don't want to fade. It should be closed immediately when the mouse cursor goes out of the form screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this violates some GUI design guideline. What happens instead?

Comment: That same code is working for me. What problem are you facing?

Comment: try this: Application.Exit();

Comment: did you notice form will be closed when you bring your mouse one of the controls on your form.

Comment: This worked for me, why can't it work for you? Can you give more details about 'not work'?

Comment: hi, thank you for responding. Application.Exit() solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several forms I prefer `Application.Exit()`.

`Form.Close()` only works for a single form application.

Answer (score 2):

To close the whole application use

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

Comment: @AndreCalil I am pretty sure that OP wants to close the application. His subject says "Close application when mouse leaves form".

Comment: @Dilshod Oh man. Yes, I'm pretty sure of it too. Sorry, upvoted

Comment: This doesn't help at all, the `Leave` event isn't firing.

Answer (score 2):

The MouseLeave event will fire if the mouse enters a child control, which is probably not what you want.

Try using a timer:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
private bool mouseEntered = false;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
  timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e) {
  mouseEntered = true;
  base.OnMouseEnter(e);
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (mouseEntered && !this.Bounds.Contains(Cursor.Position)) {
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If there is only one form in that application you are using, then `Application.Exit` will close the application itself.
2. If there is one more form that you are navigating to from the main form, then in the new form, use `Form2.Close()`, this will take you to the back to the main application that you are using.
3. If you want to close both of them, then first give `Form2.Close()` and then give `Application.Exit()`. That would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little test program to recreate your problem.

```
namespace OddFormTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public class OddForm : Form
    {
        public OddForm()
        {
            this.Leave += Leaver;
        }

        [STAThread]
        internal static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new OddForm);
        }

        private void Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close()
        }
    }
}
```

As you infer in the question. The `Leave` event doesn't fire after you leave your application.